# Javascript debugging in VS2010 without using the keyword debugger

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I'm using Visual Studio 2010, MVC3, with JQuery.
I've set breakpoints in my javascript functions.
I've checked that my settings are in debug mode.
However, the breakpoints are not being hit. There are many suggestions of using the keywork 'debugger' and making sure that some silverlight option is not checked. 
Is there not a way to get debugging to work without using the keyword 'debugger'?
I've gotten it to work on another project a while ago but for the life of me I can't recall how I did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the web application
In your solution explorer, notice a new item will appear at the top. In my case, localhost appeared.
[image]

Double click on the file to open it.
Find the line of javascript you want and set the breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Try using firebug instead --> http://getfirebug.com/